# Using node-ffi with Electron not working (cannot find message text for message number 0x%1...)

Tags: c++, dll, electron

I'm actually trying to use a `dll` with electron but I've got an error when it reaches the line:

```
const ffi = require("ffi");
```

### Error

[image: Link to error (it's in french)]

> Translation : The system cannot find message text for message number
>   0x%1 in the message file for %2

Using Electron 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

newbie here. After some research it might be because you're trying to laod a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit environment.
Check [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/the-system-cannot-find-message-text-for-message/b671711f-7e25-4b55-984e-0b81a006cae0?auth=1) for more info.